# Chemostat modeling

Tags: matlab, code-analysis, analysis

I'm learning at the moment basics of systems biology by interest this summer. I found an exercise where they give me a table with the Dilution rate, Cell concentration and Carbon substrate concentration to model the growth of cells (there's around 30 datas).

They tell us to look at [Monod equation (kinetics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monod_equation) and to suppose it's this one. 
Substrate concentration in the feed is 10 (g/L) and an excess of oxygen was
used.

They ask us to find the maximum growth rate (u_max) and saturation/monod constant (Ks). The thing is that I've only one equation and I don't know how I could program this.

I try to use MATLAB. Any ideas ?

Thanks !

Edit: I'm new on StackOverflow, can we use LATEX here ? If yes, how?

Comment: Yes I have one idea. Try learning MATLAB first. It will really help you out.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for this fabulous idea... I've of course started working on MATLAB and did a few basic things with it. However, I don't see how to start.

Comment: It is fairly easy go read some good resource. Get to know hoe to do basic stuff. Implementing equations is fairly easy then. See this for example https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/119522-implement-equation-and-solve-variable